# WCF service, two-way communication - message security none

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have created a WCF service for a client to communicate with an ASP.NET application. The service is created on the client, which the ASP.NET application can invoke. For now I'm using no security when communicating.

So far the service is created and running. The ASP.NET application has created a ServiceReference to it, but when trying to invoke a method I get the following error message (debugging on):

> The message with Action 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Easy enough, issues with the app.config. I cannot seem to find out what's the issue, since I've copied the app.config from the WCF host to the ASP. application.

App.config for the client (WCF host):

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="WSHttpBinding_Interface" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
           bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
           messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/WCF/" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_Interface" contract="WCFProject.IInterface" name="WSHttpBinding_Interface">
  <identity>
    <dns value="localhost" />
  </identity>
</endpoint>
</client>
<services>
<service name="WCFProject.Interface" behaviorConfiguration="WCFProject.InterfaceBehavior">
  <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFProject.IInterface" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_Interface" name="WCFProject.Interface.EndpointConfiguration">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
  <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
  <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
</services>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="WCFProject.InterfaceBehavior">
    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

App.config for the ASP application (ServiceReference is named InterfaceService):

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="WSHttpBinding_Interface" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
           bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" 
           messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/WCF/" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_Interface" contract="InterfaceService.IInterface" name="WSHttpBinding_Interface">
  <identity>
    <dns value="localhost" />
  </identity>
</endpoint>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The WCF service is initiated in the ASP application as following, where the WCFUrl is the url to the WCF service:

```
            //Create object of the Binding
        System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding();
        //Create endpointAddress of the Service
        System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new
        System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(WCFUrl + "?wsdl");
        //Create Client of the Service
        InterfaceService.InterfaceClient cc = new InterfaceService.InterfaceClient(binding, endpointAddress);
        //Call Service method using ServiceClient
        string ss = cc.Ping();
```

Any help pointing me to the right direction is appriciated. I've been stuck on this for a few days.
Thanks.

Update:
I have also added the following in the  on both sides:

```
       <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        <message establishSecurityContext="false"/>
      </security>
```

This without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure all attributes of the bindings security in the client configuration to match what is the server is sending out.

```
<security>
    <transport/>
    <message/>
 </security>
```

Comment: Thanks, I see I used some old app.config. I've added the same level of <security> elements, but the issue is still the same. I updated the post above.

Comment: There is something amiss with how the client is configured to access the service versus how the service is configured to communicate to the client. This is the type of error that occurs when you access a wcf service that requires https using http. The best course of action would be to start from scratch with a plain http binding with no security or quotas and build it up one at a time. On a side note I have come across this error when debugging in visual studio. When I deployed to IIS everything works. It is just that VS does not like to access the asp.net development server using https.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I'm missing the endpoint address (http://local.host:8732/WCF/) underneath the  endpoint. That's embarrasing.

Thanks.